# How to display album art using Mutagen in a PyQt5 application?

Tags: python-3.x, image, pyqt, pyqt5, mutagen

I am designing a simple mp3 player using Python3.6 and PyQt5, and am I stuck when trying to display an image inside the PyQt5 application.

I am extracting the album art using [Mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as follows:

```
pict = tags.get("APIC:").data
im = Image.open(BytesIO(pict))
im.show()
```

This opens the image in my Windows gallery, and not inside the PyQt application (obviously). My question is how do I embed this image inside the application itself such that the album art is displayed whenever a song is played?

I have tried displaying a saved image inside a label like so:

```
self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><img src=\":/Images/81+8w4dqVXL._"
                                            "Cover Art.jpg\"/></p></body></html>"))
```

However this is not really what I am after as I would need to directly save each image to the user's machine.

Any suggestions on how this can be implemented directly inside the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use PIL for this, since you can create a [QPixmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) directly from the tag data, which can then be shown in the label:

```
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
metadata = mutagen.File(filename)
for tag in metadata.tags.values():
    if tag.FrameID == 'APIC':
        pixmap.loadFromData(tag.data)
        break
self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```